# Understanding the structure of an Arch package repository mirror

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, repository, mirror

I'm trying to figure out the structure better of a Arch Linux package repository mirror. There's several folders which are pretty easy to understand, such as community, core, extra, multilib, iso, kde-unstable, gnome-unstable, etc.

But there are some others also that are slightly more confusing, such as pool, project, etc.

For example, this is the structure of the mirror http://mirror.gnomus.de/

```
../
community/
community-staging/
community-testing/
core/
extra/
gnome-unstable/
iso/
kde-unstable/
multilib/
multilib-staging/
multilib-testing/
pool/
project/
staging/
testing/
lastsync 
lastupdate
```

Is there a linux mirror tradition I'm missing here, or is this structure unique to Arch? Also, what do the less obvious folders mean? From what I can gather, it seems as though the pool folder contains all of the packages, while the rest categorize them, but I'm not sure if this is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never maintained Arch Linux mirror so the following is just my understanding of how they works.

Mirror structure (mandatory items):

- **pool/** -- that's where all packages actually resides and all other repositories contains symlinks to them. So
  maintainers can move packages between repositories and only remove one symlink and add another.
- **core/, extra/, community/, multilib/** -- stable repositories.
- **testing/, community-testing/, multilib-testing/** -- testing repositories.
- **staging/, community-staging/, multilib-staging/** -- staging repositories, used only by developers. When they
  pushing big rebuilds (like python 2->3 transition or something) they rebuild it here and then push to testing (so they
  do not spread breakage to testing).
- **iso/** -- ISO-images.
- **lastsync, lastupdate** -- mirror syncronization timestamps.

Also they may contains other elements like:

- **project/** -- ftpsync log. Can be found on Tier-2 and 3 mirrors.
- **source/** -- package tarballs.
- **other/** -- some Arch-related things. Project sources, patches, archlinux-keyring etc.